# Using Clojure with Vaadin

Tags: clojure, vaadin, compojure

Has anyone tried implementing a web application with Clojure ( using Compojure ) and Vaadin ? I had seen an article on using Clojure with JWT for creating web apps. Vaadin is based on GWT so you get a lot of the advantages of GWT ( though Vaadin is completely Server-centric). And Clojure gives the advantage that you can use any Java Based Framework, so what thoughts on the Clojure + Vaadin based web application ?

Comment: I used JWT as well as Vaadin. very nice but much more community support and documentation for Vaadin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've created an article in Vaadin Trac wiki describing such integration:

http://dev.vaadin.com/wiki/Articles/ClojureScripting

Comment: "Page not found"; I cannot find a new link

Answer (score 1):

Yes, created youcaneatat.com entirely in Clojure and vaadin. The advantages of Clojure using Clojure are that it is a Lisp, and the advantages of using Vaadin are that you get to code everything using only serverside programming techniques, so you do not need to think about Javascript callbacks or anything like that.

However, Vaadin is very client heavy, so I would only recommend this for intranet applications