# Can someone convert this Java code in to Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, vaadin

Can someone convert this into Clojure, I don't know to do the line `setMainWindow(argument)` like things....

```
import com.vaadin.Application;

class something {
    public void init() {
        Window main = new Window("The Main Window");
        setMainWindow(main);
        addComponent(new WindowOpener("Window Opener", main));
    }
}
```

**Update:**

```
package app;

import com.vaadin.Application;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;

/**
 * The Application's "main" class
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyVaadinApplication extends Application{
    private Window window;

    @Override
    public void init(){
        window = new Window("My Vaadin Application");
        setMainWindow(window);
        window.addComponent(new Button("Click Me"));
    }
}
```

There is a  "/lib/vaadin.jar" which contains all "com.vaadin.*" things. 
I think `setMainWindow(window);` is from the extended class. I am not going to write that method.

Comment: Use the curly brace toolbar button for formatting.

Comment: You might want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173091/using-clojure-with-vaadin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Literal translation:

```
(defn init []
  (let [main (Window. "The Main Window")]
    (setMainWindow main)
    (addComponent (WindowOpener. "Window Opener" main))))
```

Though it doesn't make much sense without the context.

Answer (score 0):

See http://dev.vaadin.com/wiki/Articles/ClojureScripting. Also I would suggest http://www.odesk.com.

Comment: I saw this... But I cant do this with that codings.. I am not a Clojure expert....!! But thanks a lot...!!